# Check if member value is different than in previous iteration

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a `QuerySet` of `GroupMembership` objects ordered by `product__name`, which is assigned to my template as `group_memberships`; `GroupMembership` objects have a `product` and a `group` field, both having a `name` property. In the output I’d like to render a heading tag every time `membership.product.name` changes:

```
<h1>First Product</h1>
<p>One item</p>
<p>Another item</p>
<h1>Second Product</h1>
<p>First item in Second Product</p>
```

My original idea was to introduce a helper variable where I store the last product name, and if it is different from the previous one (or empty), I render the `<h1>` line. Django, however, lacks an `{% assign %}` tag. Is there a way to do it without introducing a custom template tag/context processor? Or should I instead do the grouping somehow in my view, and assign a nested `dict` to my template? I prefer not to install any custom app for this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for membership in group_memberships %}

    {% ifchanged %}
        <h1>{{ membership.product.name }}</h1>
    {% endifchanged %}

    <p>{{ membership.group.name }}</p>

{% endif %}
```